# Jquery Remove "" from a json value

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following Json value :

```
["{"label":"0-30 Days","value":"0.00"}", "{"label":"30-60 Days","value":"0.00"}", "{"label":"60-90 Days","value":"0.00"}", "{"label":"90-180 Days","value":"50,764,332.30"}"]
```

How can I remove the "" from the data so that I remain with the following syntax ?

```
[{"label":"0-30 Days","value":"0.00"},{"label":"30-60 Days","value":"0.00"}, {"label":"60-90 Days","value":"0.00"},{"label":"90-180 Days","value":"50,764,332.30"}]
```

Comment: You have an array with 4 strings inside, is that it? It's not properly escaped, so make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array with 4 strings inside, you can try this:

```
var someArray = [
    '{"label":"0-30 Days","value":"0.00"}', 
    '{"label":"30-60 Days","value":"0.00"}', 
    '{"label":"60-90 Days","value":"0.00"}', 
    '{"label":"90-180 Days","value":"50,764,332.30"}'
];

var someJson = [];

someArray.forEach(function(item) {
    someJson.push(JSON.parse(item));
});

console.log("JSON", someJson);
```

Or you can just change the original array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i] = JSON.parse(someArray[i]);
}

console.log("Array", someArray);
```

Still, I'm not sure if that's what you want.